# Can you change where apt installs software?

Tags: apt

After 3 months of using Ubuntu I realized that apt is installing software to my SSD instead of my HDD. Presently I'm booting from my SSD but I have my home directory installed on the HDD.

Is there any way to change how apt installs?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to install software in the SSD? The main reason you have an SSD is so your installed software runs faster, no?

Comment: @Braiam, simple. I'm using a 50 gig SSD to boot from and a 500gb HDD to run normal stuff from. SSDs are prohibitively expensive, and I dont want to waste the space on stuff that doesnt need lightning fast boot up times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://ubuntuforums.org/ via [Abz's blog](https://abz89.wordpress.com/2010/02/11/change-an-apt-cache-folder-location/):

> To change apt cache permanently :
>
> ```
> cd /new/cache/is/here
> mkdir partial
> nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
> ```
>
> Add this line:
>
> ```
> dir::cache::archives /new/cache/is/here
> ```
>
> To change temporarily:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get -o dir::cache::archives="/new/cache/is/here" install packagename
> ```
>
> Or you can create a symbolic link (it will DELETE your current cache)

You can first move old cache files to somewhere else for safe keeping:

```
sudo mkdir /New_Location/newtmp
sudo cp -a /var/cache/apt/archives/* /New_Location/newtmp
```

Then create the symbolic link:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives
sudo ln -s /path/to/new/cache /var/cache/apt/archives
```

Finally move all your old cache files to your new cache location and clean up the temporary data:

```
sudo cp -a /New_Location/newtmp/* /path/to/new/cache
sudo rm -rf /New_Location/newtmp/
```

Comment: This only moves the cache, not the installation directory.

Comment: [Plagiarism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is [not cool](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134715).

Comment: This is not the first time I have seen plagiarised answers by OP. Please read: [Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do)